# Formatting a string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that (simplified) looks something like:

```
col1 col2
1     a
2     b
3     c,ddd,ee,f,5,hfsf,a
```

In col2, I need to be able to remove everything after the last 2 commas, and if it doesn't have commas just keep the value as is:

```
    col1 col2
1     a
2     b
3     c,ddd,ee
```

again, this is simplified and the solution needs to scale up to something that has 1000's of rows, and the space between each comma will not always be the same

edit:
This is got me on the right track

```
 df.col2 = df.col2.str.split(',').str[:2].str.join(',')
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: That string processing is a well-documented process.  Applying a change process to each element of a column is also well documented.  What part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: An ugly way would be `df.col2.apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.split(',')[:3]))`

Comment: can you give me a link because I haven't found anything that has helped with this issue (I've found how to strip characters out. but I couldn't quite wrap my head around how that would apply to this)

Comment: And I agree with @Prune: You will get more helpful answers if you show what you have tried yourself and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas provides access to many familiar string functions, including slicing and selection, through the `.str` attribute:

```
df.col2.str.split(',').str[:3].str.join(',')
#0           a
#1           b
#2    c,ddd,ee
```